# View bar / texte d'axe / étiquettes tags with theme_void r

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes, iris-dataset

I made a graph on the iris database like this :

[image]

here's the code that allowed me to get this graph :

```
    library(tidyverse)
iris %>%
  gather("Type", "Value",-Species) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Species, Value, fill = Type)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
  theme_bw()+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired")+
  theme_void()+
  theme(legend.position = "right",
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 13))
```

And I used the `theme_void` to have a graph with a white background and without the lines axes. But it removes the labels of the three species (Verginica, Setosa...).

how I could display at the bottom of each group of bars the labels.

the other themes proposed by R don't suit me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add this back to  theme!

```r
library(tidyverse)
iris %>%
  gather("Type", "Value",-Species) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Species, Value, fill = Type)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
  theme_bw()+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired")+
  theme_void()+
  theme(legend.position = "right",
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 13), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(),
        axis.text.x = element_text())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>